# Is throughput on higher bandwidth networks hindered by smaller UDP packet size?

Tags: networking, udp

I recently conducted an experiment on UDP throughput across 802.11g networks, using packet sizes between 100 and 1000 and bandwidths ranging from 6Mbps and 54Mbps.

I have noticed that that higher bandwidths are not performing as well as i had anticipated, and i have a feeling that this may be due to my packet sizes used. Would my throughput on the higher bandwidth networks have been higher if i had opted for larger packet size? and if so why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is also a known attack on firewalls.

The reason for this is that routers and firewalls can process a number of amount of packets (their size doesn't matter). So to calculate the bandwidth they choose a certain packet size and multiply it by the amount of packets they can process.

For instance if they calculate that 1 gbit is calculated with 512 byte packets and you use 64 byte packets instead, the bandwith is reduced to 125 mbit.

It's used as DoS attack because it's easy to saturate a line.